# Globally replace all hyphens after some 'Divider'

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Greetings to the experts, Im seeking a PCRE match/replace to perform the following...
a-b-*Divider*-Any-Text ----> a-b-*Divider*__Any__Text
a-b-c-*Divider*-w-x-y-z ---> a-b-c-*Divider*__w__x__y__z
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j ------> a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j     (nothing replaced, since no *Divider*)

So basically, I'm just trying to globally replace all of the hyphens *after*  Divider.
If replacing hyphens *before* a Divider, I just use something like `-(?=.*Divider.*)/g`
But changing this to a negative-lookahead also matches text *without* the Divider.

Can I somehow both verify 'Divider' while globally matching all of the remaining hyphens??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?:\G(?!\A)|Divider)[^-]*\K-
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1YQG7r/2). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|Divider)` - either the end of preceding match or `Divider`
- `[^-]*` - zero or more chars other than `-`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards text matched so far
- `-` - a hyphen.

Comment: A million thanks for this! I didnt even know about \G, \A, or \K, so its great knowing I still have much to learn.. Cant wait to start putting them to practice.. Now all I need are some better PCRE-compliant apps.. Thanks again!

Comment: @evangeline531 [In this YT video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsGUbvW5hsE), you can find more examples of `\G` and `\K` usage. `\A` is basically `^` here, it matches the start of string position.